# iOS in-app purchase server model

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I understand that in server model of in-App purchases in iOS, the products(non-consumables in my case) would have to be hosted on my own server. Now, with iOS 6, it seems apple allows you to upload content to their servers. Does that mean that if I have to add more products in the future, I only have to upload more content, add description and pricing, associate it with my app and submit it for approval? or do I still need to have a list of products on my own server which will be updated(with new products in the future) and downloaded by the app after purchasing and which will fetch products?

Sorry if I am sounding confusing but I could do with some clarification.

THanks.